# Show clipped text on hover with CSS

Tags: css, text, hidden

I made a common button style for buttons with different captions. The button has a fixed width so sometimes the text wont fit. Making the font smaller doesnt help because the text then gets so small its unreadable. My idea is to make the text come to the left so the part that is hidden shows on mouse hover. However, the text should move only when its too long. It should not move if it fits in the button. This is my code:

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  height:30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 5px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: "   ";
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button:hover {
  padding-right: 120px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">Short</a>
<a href="" class="button">Longer example</a>
```

it doesnt work as expected though. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: CSS can't detect text-width. You'd need javascript.

Comment: In addition to @Paulie_D, you can make a dynamic button, this means that the button can grow its width while the text is larger. But if you want to preserve the fixed width, you can't at least with pure CSS

Comment: use overflow:hidden and on hove overflow:visible

Comment: Thats not a good idea. The text would overlap the button and that looks kind of crappy. Also, I dont understand why the text wont move on hover with padding-right?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `direction` of the text on hover, so that it overflows on the left side instead of the right.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  height:30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 5px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: "   ";
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 66px;
}

.button:hover {
  direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">Short</a>
<a href="" class="button">Longer example</a>
```

Note that I had to shorten the width of the button in this snippet to make the "longer example" actually overflow.

Comment: The animation looks kinda weird but I think your solution is for now the closest thing to what Im looking for.